# Using a string as part of parameter

Tags: c#

Sorry if it's not clear. Right now my code has this:

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.NA);
```

What I want to do is to replace the NA at the end with a selected item from a listbox. I can access it by doing

```
listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

listBox1 will contain items such as NA, EU, LAN, etc and I want it so that I can do something like this

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

but I'm not sure if it will work. Can someone suggest me a way to get around this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think that your ListBox's SelectedItem would be available in Properties, simply try: `IPAddress.Parse(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());` **Or do you want to map the value of `SelectedItem` to your Setting's value** ?

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.NA` presumably return a string and `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` does too. What exactly would you expect `Properties.Settings.Default.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` to return?

Comment: listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() returns a string, which matches with a properties in the user settings. So for example, in the listBox, the selected item is NA. If I do Properties.Settings.Default.NA it'll return an IP address. So instead of writing a few if statements which checks what the SelectedItem is, I want to be able to make it return what's selected directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I believe you have a `string` value in your ListBox, which maps to `Properties`. There in properties, the actual string containing an `IPAddress` exists.

Since you can access: `Properties.Settings.Default.NA`, you can access the properties based on index as well, which would be the name of string key. So use:

```
IPAddress address  = IPAddress.Parse(
            Properties.Settings.Default[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()].ToString());
```

You may add some checks to see if you *actually* have that property. Like:

```
string listBoxItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

var valueFromProperty = Properties.Settings.Default[listBoxItem];
if (valueFromProperty != null)
{
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(valueFromProperty.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly! Just another thing, at the beginning of my program I set my listBox to add several items. Is there a way for the listBox to add items based on what's in the settings file. All the settings file will contain is the NA/EU/etc and the IP address.

Comment: @Nonono, Try: `lislistBox1.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default;`, its Winforms right ?

Comment: I'm trying that but this is the error that comes up: 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll. Additional information: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.' What do you mean by Winforms? I'm new to C#, just trying to do some programs to learn it faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
IPAddress address  = IPAddress.Parse(Settings.Default.Properties[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()].DefaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the enum as the data source for the listbox:

```
listBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
```

and then the selected item will actually be the enum value:

```
EnumType item = (EnumType)listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Make sure you replace EnumType with whatever type your enum is.